# Can I output an array without excessive spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I'm trying to take the text of a .txt file and transfer it's information to an array, the trouble is, I get the output with the words, but the output is excessively spaced. (the array must be 6*7) The file has the text: "It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen."

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class tryThings {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("2DArray.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int totalRow = 6;
        int totalColumn = 7;
        char[][] myArray = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];
        file = new java.io.File("2DArray.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        for (int row = 0; scanner.hasNextLine() && row < totalRow; row++) {
            char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn && i < chars.length; i++) {
                myArray[row][i] = chars[i];
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need the output to be in one 6*7 space (with each space filled with either a character or a space which in this is a "*"). Right now, the program outputs the entire string 7 times, it should print only once formatted to the 6*7. It's ok if the words overlap to the next line and if all the words don't fit in the array. Here's and example of how I want the output to look: [I, t, , w, a, s, ] [a, , b, r, i, g, h] [t, , c, o, l, d, ] [d, a, y, , i, n, ] [A, p, r, i, l, ,, ] [a, n, d, , t, h, e].

Comment: Hi there, perhaps use something like this to pad the string with whitespace: `String.format("%-10s", "my string");`. (Guava has `Strings.pad*` functions also which might be helpful.)

Comment: @IronMan I changed the code quite a bit to be more efficient but I came to a new issue, I edited the post. Any Ideas?

Comment: A 6*7 array can hold 42 characters. Your input string contains 73 characters. Please explain why you are doing this (it's an unusual problem statement!) and provide an example of the output that you want.

Comment: You're printing `chars` inside the inner loop. This will of course print `chars` at most 7 times, depending on the length of `chars`.

Comment: @kimbert It was an assignment, I don't know why a string longer than the space provided was necessary but that's what I got. It should look like this: https://imgur.com/4roCBTR

Comment: @kimbert So do you have any ideas? Sorry, not trying to be demanding I just am still stuck.

Comment: @ZachGoniea Are you looking for output like - `[I, t,  , w, a, s,  ]
[a,  , b, r, i, g, h]
[t,  , c, o, l, d,  ]
[d, a, y,  , i, n,  ]
[A, p, r, i, l, ,,  ]
[a, n, d,  , t, h, e]`

Comment: Please can you add into the question an explanation of the output that you want to get. I cannot access the link that you provided in the comment.

Comment: @Jatish Yes, that's what I want to come out.

Comment: @kimbert You should be able to view it now, I fixed it. https://imgur.com/gallery/4roCBTR

Comment: @kimbert there is also a description at the bottom of the question. I've already had to turn in the assignment, but I certainly still want to know how to do it. that's why I'm in a Java class, to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned code will give you the output as expected

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("2DArray.txt");

    int totalRow = 6;
    int totalColumn = 7;
    char[][] myArray = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    file = new java.io.File("2DArray.txt");
    int rowIndex = 0;


    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      // Read line from file and convert to array
      char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();

      for (int charIndex = 0; rowIndex < totalRow && charIndex < chars.length; rowIndex++, charIndex =
          charIndex + totalColumn) {
        // Copy the X=totalColumn chars from the above array to row
        System.arraycopy(chars, charIndex, myArray[rowIndex], 0,
            Math.min(totalColumn, chars.length - charIndex));
      }
    }

    for (char[] ar : myArray) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
    }
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

> There is one thing to take care of-   When First line is shorter than
>   total number of elements matrix can fit in.   It will load the next
>   line, but the new line will be started from new row in matrix, please see below example-

```
 E.g. Input -   Line1: It was a bri   
                Line2: ght cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.
```

The code is based on the confirmed output given by you, any changes required - let me know